# Pointer becomes nothing for no apparent reason

Tags: c

Greetings!

I have a simple program in qt on c.
There are two pointers to type short, used to read from file and store bits from values read.

sample code:

```
//(input is a FILE* which is opened and passed to the function)
//(output is also a FILE* which is also opened and passed to the function)

//1. Variables declaration
short* sample_buffer;
int buffer_size=1;
short samples_read;
unsigned long value_x=7;
short* nzb_buffer;
short buffer_position=-1;
int i;

//2.Memory allocation
sample_buffer= malloc(sizeof(short)*buffer_size);
nzb_buffer = malloc(sizeof(short)*value_x);

....

//3. Read from infile, one short at time, process and write it to outfile
do
{
     //3.1. Read from input file
     samples_read = fread(sample_buffer,sizeof(short),buffer_size, input);
     //3.2. Switch position inside nzb_buffer one to the right, 
     //     going back to zero if out of bounds
     buffer_position=(buffer_position+1)%value_x;

     ....

     //3.3. Put least significant bit of the just read short into nzb_buffer
     nzb_buffer[buffer_position]=sample_buffer[0]%2;

     ....

     //3.4. Write the short we just read from infile to the outfile
     for (i=0;i<samples_read;i++)
     {
         fwrite(sample_buffer,sizeof(short),1, output);
     }
} while(samples_read==buffer_size);
```

I've let unreliant pieces of code out. If you need to see something else please tell me.

Problem is, after like 10 or 15 operations of the loop, it crashes with "Segmentation fault" signal. It crashes on the fwrite() function.

I debugged and i use watch on sample_buffer. For some reason, on one exact step, the operation nzb_buffer[buffer_position]=sample_buffer[0]%2 makes sample_buffer become 0x0 (i belive, it becomes a null pointer).

This cannot be overflowing on nzb_buffer because buffer_position for that operation is 3 (out of 7 allocated for the particular array in malloc). And since each loop makes one write operation and shifts the carry, the operation of writing into nzb_buffer[3] has already happened before in the loop and did not nullify the pointer that time.

I am totally clueless what may be happening here. 
Anybody has any ideas what is going on or how do i debug it?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Added comments "what the code does"

Comment: Hum, wasn't Qt a C++ library?

Comment: To be honest, I'm struggling to understand what this code is trying to do. I feel the pieces you've left out are very relevant.

Comment: yes but i have to incorporate some c code there, so this part is in c. qt works with c as well, you just do " extern "C" " with your c code and its ok

Comment: the code reads one short from the input file, stores its least significant bit in the nzb_buffer, then writes the short what it just read to output file, then repeats, until there is nothing left in the input file

Comment: There is still lots of code in your example that does... something. Which is related to what you are trying to do in your original code, but forgot to tell us. (This is usually done using code comments.) A traditional way of finding the source of a problem is *reducing* the amount of code involved *until you can reduce it no further and still observe the faulty behaviour*. Not only does this solve 90% of your problems, it also makes it much easier for others to pinpoint the problem in the remaining 10% of cases.

Comment: I added commentary. Does that explain what happens now?

Comment: @Istrebitel: That was a good first step. However, the problem is - AFAICT - not in the code presented. Resist the temptation to simply provide *more* code. Instead, make a copy of the code in question, and then *reduce* that code set until you have the smallest possible code sample reproducing the error. Either you have an epiphany ("if I take this away, the error vanishes - but why? OOooohh..." + /facepalm). Or you end up with a **complete** code example, i.e. one that everybody here could compile and observe the same error as you - significantly increasing your chances at getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your exit condition for the loop seems to be misplaced. I would do:

```
samples_read = fread(sample_buffer,sizeof(short),buffer_size, input);
while(samples_read==buffer_size){

    [...]        

    samples_read = fread(sample_buffer,sizeof(short),buffer_size, input);
}
```

Comment: But why? do-while loop was made exacty for the loop that must always happen at least once. Do {} while is as legal as while {}, first always happens once then conditional is checked, second - the conditional is checked first, so if its falst it wont happen at all

Comment: What do you read when for instance your file is empty, or when you hit end of file? Your don't want to loop in that case. So the loop must be built so that it exits just after the fread, if it failed.

Comment: It must not be done at least once when there is no input. I'd do `while (fread(sample_buffer, sizeof(short), buffer_size, input) == buffer_size)`.

Comment: I see your point, thanks. Anyway, problem is, the bug happens in the beginning of the file, not at the end of it. And code as it is writes nothing to the outfile if nothing was read because i omitted "for (i=0;i<samples_read;i++)" loop around fwrite, since it wasnt relevant, i thought, since this time i am only doing it for 1 sample at a time, and the loop effectively always runs once except for final time